# How I can put bottom and left border on TextView?

Tags: android

Is it possible to draw a left and bottom border for a textview?

Comment: specify closer what you want just add some margin to TextView?

Comment: no.., I want add a separate lines. Somethings like as [link] (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30500290/example.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a 9-path to be your TextView's BG. That 9-patch will have only left and bottom border, so it'll suit your needs. You can read more on 9-patches here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

You can use the draw9patch tool on the SDK do draw your own 9patch, or take en existing 9patch from the Android source code, or even from the other places on the internet, like this blog http://android9patch.blogspot.co.il/ which also have some tutorials on how to create 9 patched.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the TextView inside of another layout with an XML shape similar to the one below:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/detailtable_border" />
        </shape>
   </item>

   <item android:left="1.5dp" android:right="1.5dp" android:bottom="2dp">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/detailrow_bg_normal" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But how, with "left and bottom" only ?